# Relationship between Diameter of the Wheel and the Turning Radius

Tags: wheels

Please explain the relationship between Diameter of the Wheel and the Turning Radius of the vehicle.(Car or Bus).  Does the length of the vehicle also matters.

Comment: In my language the term "Turning Radius" often get confused with the "scrub radius" due to similar naming. Unlike the turning radius, the scrub radius _will_ be affected by the wheel diameter (and offset (ET)) http://forums.pelicanparts.com/uploads2/FrontView1067799293.jpg

Comment: In theory wheel size has no effect on the turning radius. However in practice I've experienced other ways. I used to do skateboarding in my childhood. I used different wheelsets on the same board and found that smaller wheels can turn in smaller radius while basically all the other parameters (wheelbase, track, steering system, bearings, wheel width and material) were the same. I think it has to do something with the contact patch size and friction.

Answer (score 7):

There is no relationship between wheel size and turning circle - the turning radius of the vehicle is defined by the geometry of the front suspension, and the wheelbase and overhangs of the vehicle.

For example, the traditional London Taxi is famous for having a very small turning circle, as it is designed to cope with very narrow streets. This is achieved through clever steering design - it uses the same size wheels as most other similarly sized cars.